# Why random.choices is faster than NumPy’s random choice?

Tags: numpy, random

I am trying to do random sampling in the most efficient way in Python, however, I am puzzled because when using the numpy's random.choices()  was slower than using the random.choices()

```
import numpy as np
import random

np.random.seed(12345)

# use gamma distribution
shape, scale = 2.0, 2.0 
s = np.random.gamma(shape, scale, 1000000)
meansample = []

samplesize = 500

%timeit meansample = [ np.mean( np.random.choice( s, samplesize, replace=False)) for _ in range(500)]
23.3 s ± 229 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit meansample = [np.mean(random.choices(s, k=samplesize)) for x in range(0,500)]
152 ms ± 324 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

23 Seconds vs 152 ms is a lot of time

What i'am doing wrong?

Comment: `random.choices` allows repeat, while `np.random.choice( ..., replace=False)` doesn't.

Comment: @Divakar probably a typo on OPs behalf, but `np.random.choice` does have better performing alternatives without replacement.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem What alternatives are we talking about? Well OP is asking for `replace=False` case and that is slower than `random.choices`, but those are two different things. While with `replace=True`, which would be same as `random.choices` is faster. So, the question when comparing the similar functionality doesn't hold true.

Comment: @Divakar I agree that `random.choices` is probably meant to be `random.sample`. However, `random.sample` does outperform `np.random.choice` without replacement. If one uses `np.random.Generator.choice` instead of `np.random.choice`, `numpy` ends up faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues here. First, for the pure-Python `random` library, you probably mean to use `sample` instead of `choices` to sample without replacement. That alters the benchmark somewhat. Second, `np.random.choice` has better performing alternatives for sampling without replacement. This is a known [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2764) related to random generator API. You can use `np.random.Generator` to get better performance. My timings:

```
%timeit meansample = [ np.mean( np.random.choice( s, samplesize, replace=False)) for _ in range(500)]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 12.4 s per loop

%timeit meansample = [np.mean(random.choices(s, k=samplesize)) for x in range(0,500)]
# 10 loops, best of 3: 118 ms per loop

sl = s.tolist()
%timeit meansample = [np.mean(random.sample(sl, k=samplesize)) for x in range(0,500)]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 219 ms per loop

g = np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64())
%timeit meansample = [ np.mean( g.choice( s, samplesize, replace=False)) for _ in range(500)]
# 10 loops, best of 3: 25 ms per loop
```

So, without replacement, `random.sample` outperforms `np.random.choice` but is slower than `np.random.Generator.choice`.