Efficient implementation for random sampling
If you have 4 lists A, B, C, and D that contain objects of particular length, like list A has n_a elements and all the elements are of width 1, list B has n_b elements and all the elements are of width 2, list C has n_c elements and all the elements are of width 3, and list D has n_d elements and all the elements are of width 4. The goal is to create an array whose elements are randomly sampled from A, B, C and D according to a user defined probability distribution like {1: 0.25, 2: 0.25, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.0}. For instance, with distribution={1: 0.25, 2: 0.25, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.0} the output grid should yield random elements with roughly 25% 1-width elements from list A, 25% 2-width elements from list B and 50% 3-width elements from list C, while disallowing 4-width elements.
Here is how I am randomly sampling elements from all 4 lists:
import numpy as np
import random

A = [1, 2, 3]
B = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
C = [111, 222, 333]
D = ['aaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc']

num_of_rows = 4  # no. of rows in the final grid
num_of_coulmns = 5  # no. of columns in the final grid

# Define the probabilities
p_A = 0.25
p_B = 0.25
p_C = 0.5
p_D = 0.0

probabilities = [p_A, p_B, p_C, p_D]

# Create the random length array by sampling from the lists
result_array = []

for _ in range(num_of_rows):
    # Choose a list based on the probabilities
    chosen_list = random.choices([A, B, C, D], weights=probabilities, k=1)[0]

    # Sample a random element from the chosen list
    element = random.choice(chosen_list)

    # Append the element to the result array
    result_array.append(element)

But this method will be too inefficient for larger values of rows and columns of grid (like 1000). Is there a better way to achieve this.

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629890/why-random-choices-is-faster-than-numpy-s-random-choice

Do the lengths of the elements affect anything? For the algorithm, could you not 1) sample the number of elements to be selected from each list, 2) randomly choose (with replacement, presumably) that number from each list, and 3) shuffle the results? How do the number of rows and columns come into play?

This is a smaller simplified version of a complex problem that I am working on. After I have the array of random samples, I want to arrange the samples in a grid so that it creates a random grid filled with elements but the size of that grid is going to be huge (>2000) and not always known.

If you do not mind using np.random.choice you could do:
sizes = np.r_[len(A), len(B), len(C), len(D)]

np.random.choice(A+B+C+D, (num_of_rows, num_of_coulmns), p=np.repeat(probabilities/sizes, sizes))



You could use tuple(). (Or possibly set() which is very fast, yet that depends, if you can use set()).

import numpy as np
import random


def _random_sampling(r, c):
    result_array = tuple()
    for _ in range(r):
        row = tuple()
        for _ in range(c):
            i = np.searchsorted(cum_prob, random.random())
            chosen_list = lists[i]
            row += (random.choice(chosen_list),)
        result_array += (row,)
    return result_array


lists = ((1, 2, 3), ('aa', 'bb', 'cc'), (111, 222, 333), ('aaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc'))
probabilities = [0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.0]
cum_prob = np.cumsum(probabilities)

print(_random_sampling(5, 5))



Prints

((333, 111, 3, 111, 3), ('aa', 'bb', 222, 333, 'aa'), (1, 1, 222, 333,
2), (222, 222, 222, 222, 222), ('aa', 'aa', 1, 111, 222))


You can Randomly sample from large pool of pre-sampled elements according to the given probabilities using np.random.choice
import numpy as np

A = [1, 2, 3]
B = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
C = [111, 222, 333]
D = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']

probabilities = [0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.0]

num_of_rows = 1000
num_of_columns = 1000
total_elements = num_of_rows * num_of_columns

list_indices = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3], size=total_elements, p=probabilities)

lists = [A, B, C, D]

result_array = []

list_sizes = [len(lst) for lst in lists]

for index in list_indices:
    if probabilities[index] > 0:
        chosen_list = lists[index]
        element = chosen_list[np.random.randint(list_sizes[index])]
        result_array.append(element)

result_array = np.array(result_array).reshape((num_of_rows, num_of_columns))

print(result_array)

Execution results comparison
Grid Size (rows x Cols) Your code(sec)  New Method Time (sec)
10 x 10                 0.0018         0.0007
100 x 100               0.0307         0.0036
500 x 500               0.7540         0.0461
1000 x 1000             3.0951         0.1956
2000 x 2000             12.1206        0.8626

